# Sorting a list of tuples in by numeric interpretation of non-zero-padded number strings

Tags: python, sorting

I have a python list

```
l = [('insert_0', 'gtttaattgag'), ('insert_1', 'tttaattgagt'), ('insert_10', 'gttgtcatatg'), ('insert_11', 'ttgtcatatgt'), ('insert_12', 'tgtcatatgtt'), ('insert_2', 'ttaattgagtt'), ('insert_3', 'taattgagttg'), ('insert_4', 'aattgagttgt'), ('insert_5', 'attgagttgtc'), ('insert_6', 'ttgagttgtca'), ('insert_7', 'tgagttgtcat'), ('insert_8', 'gagttgtcata'), ('insert_9', 'agttgtcatat')]
```

I want it sorted so that it looks like

```
l_needed = [('insert_0', 'gtttaattgag'), ('insert_1', 'tttaattgagt'),('insert_2', 'ttaattgagtt'),('insert_3', 'taattgagttg'), ('insert_4', 'aattgagttgt'), ('insert_5', 'attgagttgtc'), ('insert_6', 'ttgagttgtca'), ('insert_7', 'tgagttgtcat'), ('insert_8', 'gagttgtcata'), ('insert_9', 'agttgtcatat'),('insert_10', 'gttgtcatatg'), ('insert_11', 'ttgtcatatgt'), ('insert_12', 'tgtcatatgtt'),..]
```

i.e. `l` is sorted in ascending order of the subscript of `"insert"`. I tried
`l.sort()` does not produce `l_needed`. Can you suggest edits?

Comment: This is no exact duplicate, since the OP's main question is about sorting by not zero-padded number strings

Comment: It is not identical, but it is closely related. The type of problem is the same and the solution is similar. Taking a look at the other question, along with your solution, should give a pretty clear idea on how to deal with this class of problems, whatever the sorted list's element structure may be.

Answer (score 5):

You can split off the number and convert it to an integer:

```
In [7]: sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x[0].rsplit('_', 1)[-1]))
Out[7]:
[('insert_0', 'gtttaattgag'),
 ('insert_1', 'tttaattgagt'),
 ('insert_2', 'ttaattgagtt'),
 ('insert_3', 'taattgagttg'),
 ('insert_4', 'aattgagttgt'),
 ('insert_5', 'attgagttgtc'),
 ('insert_6', 'ttgagttgtca'),
 ('insert_7', 'tgagttgtcat'),
 ('insert_8', 'gagttgtcata'),
 ('insert_9', 'agttgtcatat'),
 ('insert_10', 'gttgtcatatg'),
 ('insert_11', 'ttgtcatatgt'),
 ('insert_12', 'tgtcatatgtt')]
```